# How can I force a sync of the entire filesystem to disk in Java?

Tags: java, filesystems, outputstream, disk

How can I force a sync of the entire filesystem to disk in Java?
It seems I can only force sync single files using getFd() from file-streams.

I can call sync with a shell, but how can I do it in Java?

Comment: I've faced the same issue, and for now I am considering calling `sync` using JNI. My project is gonna be restricted to POSIX systems for that reason. Let me know if you ended up going through different ways.